# Java parallel stream internals

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I noticed that depends of implementation of doSth() method (if thread sleeps for a constant or random amount of time) a parallel stream is being executed differently.

Example:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class AtomicInt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        out.println("Result: " + count());
    }

    public static int count() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(10);

        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

        forkJoinPool.submit(() -> IntStream
                .rangeClosed(1, 20)
                .parallel()
                .map(i -> doSth(counter))
                .forEach(i -> out.println(">>>forEach: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " value: " + i))
        ).get();

        return counter.get();
    }

    private static int doSth(AtomicInteger counter) {
        try {
            out.println(">>doSth1: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(100 + new Random().nextInt(1000));
//            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        int counterValue = counter.incrementAndGet();
        out.println(">>doSth2: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " value: " + counterValue);

        return counterValue;
    }
}
```

Each number is being processed in the order:

```
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-10
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8 value: 1
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8 value: 1
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15 value: 2
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15 value: 2
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11 value: 3
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11 value: 3
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2 value: 4
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2 value: 4
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9 value: 5
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9 value: 5
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11 value: 6
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11 value: 6
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 value: 7
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 value: 7
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15 value: 8
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15 value: 8
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8 value: 9
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8 value: 9
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13 value: 10
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13 value: 10
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9 value: 11
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9 value: 11
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15 value: 12
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15 value: 12
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-10 value: 13
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-10 value: 13
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4 value: 14
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4 value: 14
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6 value: 15
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6 value: 15
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11 value: 16
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11 value: 16
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2 value: 17
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2 value: 17
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13 value: 18
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13 value: 18
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 value: 19
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 value: 19
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8 value: 20
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8 value: 20
Result: 20
```

When I change doSth() method to sleep always for 1s instead of a random time, then result is being computed out of sequence:

```
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-10
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 value: 1
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-10 value: 2
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6 value: 3
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6 value: 3
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-10 value: 2
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 value: 1
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-10
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15 value: 4
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9 value: 10
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8 value: 7
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8 value: 7
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4 value: 9
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4 value: 9
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11 value: 8
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13 value: 6
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2 value: 5
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13 value: 6
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11 value: 8
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9 value: 10
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15 value: 4
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2 value: 5
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15
>>doSth1: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-10 value: 12
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-10 value: 12
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6 value: 11
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 value: 13
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6 value: 11
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 value: 13
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9 value: 15
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2 value: 20
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2 value: 20
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15 value: 19
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15 value: 19
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8 value: 14
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11 value: 17
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4 value: 16
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13 value: 18
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4 value: 16
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11 value: 17
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8 value: 14
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9 value: 15
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13 value: 18
Result: 20
```

Is it a coincidence or there is an explanation for this behaviour ?

Comment: this is interesting indeed

Comment: This is not the way `Random` must be used. Generating a fresh random sequence to pick only one value out of it for each element of the stream is a very bad pattern.

Comment: Agreed, I imagine you wouldn't see this behavior with `ThreadLocalRandom`.

Comment: @dimo414 so I thought too... but you would get the same output with `ThreadLocalRandom `

Comment: @Eugene: indeed, the type of random is entirely irrelevant. You could even use `Thread.currentThread().hashCode()%100` instead. That’s just distracting from what’s actually happening.

Comment: @Holger thanks for your explanation, the misuse of `Random` is clearly a red herring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the time, you are executing the `sleep` statement, there is no defined order. While the stream created via `IntStream.range` has a defined encounter order, you are turning the operation into an unordered one by *ignoring* the actual `int` value.

The first action that produces a perceivable order, is `counter.incrementAndGet()`. Before that, it didn’t matter which thread reached that point and which stream element it is associated with. It gets its number right at this point from the `AtomicInteger`. After that, only two additional actions using the number are performed, printing two messages using that number. All that matters for these two different results, is whether these three actions, `counter.incrementAndGet()` and printing these two messages, are intercepted by another thread.

We can easily strip this scenario down to

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
es.invokeAll(Collections.nCopies(20, () -> {
    out.println("1st: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    Thread.sleep(100 + new Random().nextInt(1000));
//    Thread.sleep(1000);
    int counterValue = counter.incrementAndGet();
    out.println("2nd: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " value: " + counterValue);
    out.println("3rd: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " value: " + counterValue);
    return null;
}));
es.shutdown();
```

Note that for `invokeAll`, there is no defined ordering at all, but, as said, it doesn’t matter. The tasks get their sequence number assigned as late as when calling `incrementAndGet()`. The behavior is the same as with the stream example.

---

While I always emphasize that *concurrent* does not mean *parallel*, due to the unspecified execution times and thread scheduling behavior, there is still a good chance that short identical code started at the same time runs truly parallel when no background activity puts unpredictable workload on the CPU cores.

When all threads run in parallel, they hit the internal synchronization of `out.println` at the same time and only one thread can proceed and the others are put into the queue. Then, the *unfair* nature of `synchronized` comes into play. An arbitrary thread will win, afterwards, an arbitrary thread will be put back to schedule. This causes the numbers to be printed in random order.

When you let the threads sleep a random amount of time, they are not running exactly parallel anymore, raising the chance to reach the print statement at different times, being able to execute them uncontended. Which thread will reach this point first, is random, but since they get their numbers assigned *after* the sleep, the first thread reaching this point will get the number one, and so on.

Comment: does that mean that the OP (and me for example) got really lucky to see ordered output? I really tried understanding this answer of yours :|

Comment: @Eugene: no, the code basically says “gimme the next number in sequence”, followed by immediately printing the number. It’s actually a matter of luck seeing them out of order, because that only happens when the threads are aligned, doing the same thing at the same time, having contention at the print statement. Unaligning them, e.g. by random wait, is easier than getting them aligned.

Comment: on way or another - this is non-deterministic as far as I can tell

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the cause of this behaviour is in the call to `nextInt` in `java.util.Random` class (Java 8).

```
>     protected int next(int bits) {
>         long oldseed, nextseed;
>         AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
>         do {
>             oldseed = seed.get();
>             nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
>         } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
>         return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
>     }
```

If you do not execute `java.util.Random.nextInt(int)`, but pre-compute the random values, the result is still out of sequence - or if you create your own Random class derived from `java.util.Random` and override the method `protected int next(int bits)` to return any constant integer. I have tried to pre-compute the random values, like so:

```
private static final int[] randomIntervals = IntStream.range(0, 20)
            .map(i -> new Random().nextInt(1000) + 100)
            .toArray();
```

And then used it in the `doSth` method:

```
private static int doSth(AtomicInteger counter) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(randomIntervals[counter.intValue()]);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    int counterValue = counter.incrementAndGet();
    out.println(">>doSth2: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " value: " + counterValue);

    return counterValue;
}
```

The result looks similar to the version of the code which uses simply a `Thread.sleep(1000)` like:

```
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-26 value: 8
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 value: 4
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 value: 4
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8 value: 7
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8 value: 7
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-25 value: 1
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-25 value: 1
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15 value: 6
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15 value: 6
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-29 value: 5
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-29 value: 5
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4 value: 2
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4 value: 2
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-18 value: 3
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-18 value: 3
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-26 value: 8
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11 value: 9
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11 value: 9
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-22 value: 10
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-22 value: 10
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 value: 11
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-25 value: 12
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-25 value: 12
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8 value: 13
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-8 value: 13
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 value: 11
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-29 value: 14
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-29 value: 14
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4 value: 15
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4 value: 15
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15 value: 16
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15 value: 16
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-18 value: 17
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-18 value: 17
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-26 value: 18
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-26 value: 18
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-22 value: 19
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-22 value: 19
>>doSth2: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11 value: 20
>>>forEach: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11 value: 20
```

Another experiment was to just call the constructor of `java.util.Random`, but not `nextInt`. Again the result is out of sequence:

```
private static int doSth(AtomicInteger counter) {
    try {
        Random r = new Random();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    int counterValue = counter.incrementAndGet();
    out.println(">>doSth2: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " value: " + counterValue);

    return counterValue;
}
```

Comment: but even if it's synchronized different threads should reach that synchronization point at different times

Comment: actually since the OP createa a new `Random` istance all time, this makes no sense even more.

Comment: You are right: it is not the constructor. It is the call to nextInt(1000) which is synchronizing the threads. My assumption was not correct.

Comment: Answer was updated to point out that the problem is not int the constructor of `java.util.Random`, but in the method `nextInt(int)` of this class.